# Undefined in Firebase Functions with Realtime Database

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have two functions in Firebase. The first one is ok:

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/itemADividir/{itemId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
    const oque = snapshot.val();
    const quem = oque.userOrigem;
    const itemADV = oque.itemAdividir;
    const quanto = oque.itemValor;
    return pegaTokenUser(oque.userDestino).then(userTk =>{
        let payload ={
            notification: {
                title: 'Solicitação - Notificação InfSocial',
                body: `${quem} quer compartilhar ${itemADV} no valor de ${quanto} com vc`,
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            }       
        };
        console.log(`${quem} quer compartilhar ${itemADV} no valor de ${quanto} com vc`)
        console.log(`token ${userTk}`)
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTk, payload)

    })

    })
```

[image]

The second is returning undefined in userRecusado:

```
exports.itemRecusado = functions.database.ref('/ItemDividirNegado/{itemId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const itemId = context.params.itemId;
    const oRecusado = snapshot.val();
    const userRecusado = oRecusado.userOrigem;
    console.log(`item ${itemId} recusado ${userRecusado}`)

    return pegaTokenUser(userRecusado).then(userTk =>{
        let payload ={
            notification: {
                title: 'Solicitação - Notificação InfSocial',
                body: `${oRecusado.userDestino} recusou compartilhar ${oRecusado.itemADV} com vc`,
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            }       
        };
        console.log(`${oRecusado.userDestino} recusou compartilhar ${oRecusado.itemADV} com vc`)
        console.log(`token ${userTk}`)
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTk, payload)
    })
})
```

[image]

Here is the function to get the token from users:

```
    function pegaTokenUser(userGet){


        let userGet2 = userGet.replace ('.','') 

        let dbRef = admin.database().ref('/UserTokens');
        let defer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
                let data = snap.val();
                let userTk;
                for (var user in data) {
                    if(data[user].user === userGet2){
                        userTk = (data[user].token);
                    }
                }
                resolve (userTk)
            },(err) => {
                reject(err);   
            });
        });
        return defer 
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? This two functions do the same thing, but the second one does not get the property of the created record.

The full file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/itemADividir/{itemId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{

    const oque = snapshot.val();
    const quem = oque.userOrigem;
    const itemADV = oque.itemAdividir;
    const quanto = oque.itemValor;

    return pegaTokenUser(oque.userDestino).then(userTk =>{
        let payload ={
            notification: {
                title: 'Solicitação - Notificação InfSocial',
                body: `${quem} quer compartilhar ${itemADV} no valor de ${quanto} com vc`,
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            }       
        };
        console.log(`${quem} quer compartilhar ${itemADV} no valor de ${quanto} com vc`)
        console.log(`token ${userTk}`)
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTk, payload)

    })

    })

exports.itemRecusado = functions.database.ref('/ItemDividirNegado/{itemId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const itemId = context.params.itemId;
    const oRecusado = snapshot.val();

    const userRecusado = oRecusado.userOrigem;

    console.log(`item ${itemId} recusado ${userRecusado}`)
    // the output
    //itemRecusado
    //item 1586992687992 recusado **undefined**

    return pegaTokenUser(userRecusado).then(userTk =>{
         let payload ={
            notification: {
                title: 'Solicitação - Notificação InfSocial',
                body: `${oRecusado.userDestino} recusou compartilhar ${oRecusado.itemADV} com vc`,
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            }       
        };
        console.log(`${oRecusado.userDestino} recusou compartilhar ${oRecusado.itemADV} com vc`)
        console.log(`token ${userTk}`)
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTk, payload)

    })


})    

    function pegaTokenUser(userGet){


        let userGet2 = userGet.replace ('.','') 

        let dbRef = admin.database().ref('/UserTokens');
        let defer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
                let data = snap.val();
                let userTk;
                for (var user in data) {
                    if(data[user].user === userGet2){
                        userTk = (data[user].token);
                    }
                }
                resolve (userTk)
            },(err) => {
                reject(err);   
            });
        });
        return defer 
    }


exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
 });

 exports.TrocaEmoki = functions.database.ref('/Chat/{pathStr}/{tStamp}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
      const pathStr = context.params.pathStr;
      const tStamp = context.params.tStamp;

      console.log(`Nova mensagem ${tStamp} na mesa ${pathStr}`)

      const mensagem = snapshot.val()
      const text = addEmoji(mensagem.text)
      return snapshot.ref.update({text})
  })

  function addEmoji(text) {
    //return text.replace(/\bpizza\b/g, '')

    var regex1 = /pizza/,
        regex2 = /hotdog/,
        regex3 = /vinho/,
        regex4 = /hamburguer/,
        regex5 = /taco/,
        regex6 = /fritas/,
        regex7 = /sushi/,
        regex8 = /churrasco/,
        regex9 = /pipoca/,
        regex10 = /peixe/,
        regex11 = /cerveja/,
        regex12 = /sorvete/,
        alimento = text;

    switch(true){
        case regex1.test(alimento) : 
             return text.replace(/\bpizza\b/g, '');
             break;
         case regex2.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bhotdog\b/g, '');
             break;
         case regex3.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bvinho\b/g, '');
             break;
         case regex4.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bhamburguer\b/g, '');
             break;
         case regex5.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\btaco\b/g, '');
             break;  
         case regex6.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bfritas\b/g, '');
             break;  
        case regex7.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bsushi\b/g, '');
             break;      
        case regex8.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bchurrasco\b/g, '');
             break;    
        case regex9.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bpipoca\b/g, '');
             break;    
        case regex10.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bpeixe\b/g, '');
             break;    
        case regex11.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bcerveja\b/g, '');
             break;        
        case regex12.test(alimento): 
             return text.replace(/\bsorvete\b/g, '');
             break;        
     default:
     return text;       
         }
  }
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should use ``` instead of <code>.

Comment: If you can share the complete file or bigger part of the code it can be easier to help you find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My code was inserting values one by one in Realtime database (name, than id, than item, than value...). 
I did the same that was doing in the first case (make an object with values and than update the database with this object) and than update the database. That's it.